# How to change "Mixed Platforms" to "Any CPU" in VS2008 for VC++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How can i change the project build target from "Mixed Platforms" to "Any CPU" in Visual Stuodio 2008. Where can i find these settings.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build->Configuration Manager->Select Debug/Release->Platform

[image]